# What data types are supported for @InvocableVariable?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

The documentation states the following

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm

> The data type of the invocable variable must be an Apex class or a list of Apex classes.

This is obviously 100% wrong because the same page lists a bunch of examples of primitive data types using the @InvocableVariable annotation

```
global ID leadId;

@InvocableVariable(required=true)
global String convertedStatus;

@InvocableVariable
global ID accountId;

@InvocableVariable
global ID contactId;

@InvocableVariable
global Boolean overWriteLeadSource;

@InvocableVariable
global Boolean createOpportunity;

@InvocableVariable
global String opportunityName;

@InvocableVariable
global ID ownerId;

@InvocableVariable
global Boolean sendEmailToOwner;
```

Also, in my org, I can use the annotation on a list of SObjects, even though this is not documented

```
 @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
public List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems;
```

That said, when I try to reference said variable in a Flow, I get an internal server error.

Does anyone know why the documentation is so outdated/wrong and which are the truly supported data types for this annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [V45.0 version of the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm)

This looks more like what one would expect from the examples:

> The data type of the invocable variable must be one of the following:
>
> A primitive data type or a list of a primitive data type – the generic Object type is not supported.
>
> An sObject type or a list of an sObject type – the generic sObject type is not supported.

Apex types [were added in V46.0](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_data_integration.htm). There are a slew of examples of ApexTypes as return variables in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/kkgthb/Salesforce-Flow-Apex-Defined-Data-Types-Examples)

See also [apex-types for Flow doc example](https://katiekodes.com/flow-apex-defined-data-types/). be sure your Apex Type is an outer class

Comment: So it seems that the newer version has the wrong data types

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan - you should file doc feedback

Comment: do you know how? I don't have premier support. Basic support is allergic to the word "apex"

Comment: There's a feedback button on the doc page

Comment: Thanks! will do